# One to Many comparison in pandas two excel column comparison?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am comparing two spreadsheets, the second spreadsheet has repeated occurrences of the value in one column, the first spreadsheet has values in which some values match with the first spreadsheet. I want to create another one column in the second spreadsheet and copy the related phone number from the first sheet

**df1:**

```
df1 = pd.Dataframe({"name":["a","b","c"],"phone number":[1,2,3]})
```

**df2:**

```
df2 = pd.Dataframe({"name":["a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b"]})
```

**Expected Output:**

```
**name phno**
a      1
a      1
a      1 
a      1 
b      2
b      2
b      2
b      2
```

comparing two excel **name** based on **one_to_many** relations and create one new column in **dataframe2** as **phno** and copy the related  **phone number** value from **dataframe1**

Thanks for your contribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map`. create a `dict` of `df1['name']: df1['phone number']` and map to `df2['name']`

```
 df2['phno']=df2.name.map(dict(zip(df1.name, df1['phone number'])))



 name  phno
0    a     1
1    a     1
2    a     1
3    a     1
4    b     2
5    b     2
6    b     2
7    b     2
```

Comment: is there any possible  assign dummy value in phno if doesn't match the name

Comment: Not quite understood what you mean. Example?

Comment: in case the name has  "d"  value in df2 and it didn't match with df1 so I need to assign one value to phno column like a '0'

Comment: Try `df2['phno']=df2.name.map(dict(zip(df1.name, df1['phone number']))).fillna(0)`

Comment: happy to hear, all the best

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard `pd.merge` here:

```
In [1302]: df2.merge(df1, on='name')
Out[1302]: 
  name  phone number
0    a             1
1    a             1
2    a             1
3    a             1
4    b             2
5    b             2
6    b             2
7    b             2
```